# Can't import library in Eclipse after adding external JAR

Tags: java, eclipse

I imported a library by going to `Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries > Add External Jars` and selected the file but the library wasn't accessible (when trying to import in java code). Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "the library wasn't accessible?"

Comment: can you see it in the "Referenced Libraries" part of your project in the package explorer?

Answer (score 1):

In MANIFEST.MF add

```
Bundle-ClassPath: lib/external.jar,
 .
```

and in build.properties (lib is folder in project with external jars)

```
bin.includes = plugin.xml,\
               META-INF/,\
               .,\
               lib/
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to refresh the eclipse project using `File->Refresh`.

Then all your imports will work perfect.